# add uiview above uitableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I use this [ENSwiftSideMenu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu)
it's just a tableView written programmatically,
I want to add a custom view above `UITableView` in this side menu,
this view contain an `Image` and text label, like this

[image]

How I can do that? and this view's outlet where should I write it? because I just have a tableview class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `viewController` where you are creating `tableView`, Just set your custom view as `tableHeaderView` in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
let headerView = CustomHeaderView()
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

**Edit:** Follow this steps to set custom `tableHeaderView`.

**1 )** Create `UIView` with xib and add Image and Label or other thing that you want inside the `UIView`.

**2 )** Initialize its object in your viewController where you have added tableView.

```
 let view = CustomHederView()
 view.imageView.image = image //Set image that you want
 view.lblName.text = Name // Set Name
```

**3 )** Set this custom view as `tableHeaderView`

```
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view
```

Comment: thank you, but how I can add content like image or label to this view?